# This rule will never be matched: Why?

Tags: f#

I have the following function:

```ml
let hasColumnValue<'columnType> columnName (value: 'columnType) (row: KeyValuePair<int, ObjectSeries<string>>) =
    let columnValue =
        Series.get columnName row.Value :?> 'columnType

    match columnValue with
    | value -> true
    | _ -> false
```

The default pattern matching is flagged as "This rule will never be matched"

=> I don't understand why

Thanks in advance

Comment: Upvoted because this is such a common mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First pattern always matches because it's binding to variable. If variable with same name exists, it gets shadowed. But, if name refers to *literal* binding, then pattern succeeds if value equals to underlying constant value

```ml
let x = 1
[<Literal>] 
let Three = 3

match 2 with
| Three -> printfn "Three"
| x -> printfn "%d" x 
// prints 2

match 3 with
| Three -> printfn "Three"
| x -> printfn "%d" x 
// prints Three
```

In your case it will be most clear to use equality instead of pattern matching

```ml
 let hasColumnValue<'columnType when 'columnType: equality> columnName (value: 'columnType) (row: KeyValuePair<int, ObjectSeries<string>>) =
    let columnValue =
        Series.get columnName row.Value :?> 'columnType

    columnValue = value
```

Comment: Thanks JL0PD! One minor edit: need to add the type equality constraint: let hasColumnValue<'columnType when 'columnType: equality> ...

Comment: @MathieuFrançois, glad I've helped

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you can't pattern match on values, so the first case acts as a catch-all. I would suggest replacing the entire match expression with `columnValue = value`.